# looking for the absorption spectrum of polyene

Tags: organic-chemistry

I am looking for the absorption spectrum of linear polyenes (1,3,5-hexatriene, 1,3,5,7-Octatetraene, 1,3,5,7,9-decapentaene, etc..) in the range of UV and Visible light wavelength.

I see the data at the 2nd page of the PDF (*1). In the table, I see the max absorption wave length for hexatriene is 268nm.

| name | $\lambda_{max}$ |
| --- | --- |
| ethylene | 163nm |
| butadiene | 217nm |
| hexatriene | 268nm |
| octatetraene | 304nm |

But I see another webpage(*2) says hxatriene's wave length is 258nm.

```
The absorbance due to the π – π* transition in 1,3,5-hexatriene, for example, occurs at 258 nm.
```

Where do you look for linear polyenes absorption spectrum data?

(*1) https://www.chem.purdue.edu/courses/chm424/Handouts/14.2%20Alkenes%20and%20Aromatics.pdf

(*2)
https://courses.lumenlearning.com/suny-mcc-organicchemistry/chapter/interpreting-uv-spectra/

Comment: Hexatriene can exists as cis- and trans-isomers.

Comment: These are the wavelengths of the maximum of an absorption band so are probably only accurate to a few nm but I found 268 nm for the hexatriene, so 258 could be a typo.

Comment: @ porphyrin: According to [this article](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja01495a036), both isomers of hexatriene shows absorbance at $245, 255,$ and $\pu{265 nm}$.